# Azure Devops Marketplace - Azure Devops Server 2020 Support

Tags: azure-devops, azure-marketplace, azure-devops-server, azure-devops-server-2020

Is Azure Devops Server 2020 supported in the marketplace yet? I've recently build an extension and added support for ADO Server 2019, but when I update the installation targets to include the new server version I don't see any changes in the marketplace that show that my extension supports 2020 ADO

My Manifest file has the following:

```
"targets": [
    {
      "id": "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Cloud"
    },
    {
      "id": "Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Server",
      "version": "[17.0, 18.0)"
    }
  ]
```

Where version 18.0 should be Azure Devops Server 2020

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Azure DevOps Server 2020 is supported in market place. However, we still need to update the code from our side to reflect this in the UI. We are working on making this change.
However, there is no blocker as such to use marketplace for Server 2020.

Comment: I've done both of these but none of these change the view in the marketplace to show that Devops Server 2020 is supported. We also don't want to have support for older TFS which is why I want to specify only 2019 and 2020 devops server. But I did change my manifest this morning to make it so we support all `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services` but Azure Devops Server still doesn't show as supported. So does the marketplace not know that Azure Devops Server is released?

Comment: `I don't see any changes in the marketplace that show that my extension supports 2020 ADO` Do you refer to display azure devops server 2020 in Works with as shown in this [figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xScKx.png)?

Comment: yeah thats what we're looking at is that figure on the side bar in the marketplace extension page

Comment: Our engineer provided the answer in this [ticket](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1227349/azure-devops-marketplace-extension-does-not-suppor.html): Azure DevOps Server 2020 is supported in market place. However, we still need to update the code from our side to reflect this in the UI. We are working on making this change.
However, there is no blocker as such to use marketplace for Server 2020.